# Как вызывать метод контроллера без перехода по ссылке?

Tags: c#, asp.net

Есть `HomeController`, в котором метод `GetReport`. В Index.html есть кнопка, при клике  на которую вызывается этот метод. Все работает отлично, но в урл у меня отображается след. ссылка

```
http://localhost/Home/GetReport
```

Можно ли как то сделать, чтобы метод вызывался, но переход по ссылке не происходил. Ну или чтобы в строке он не отображался

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("GetReport", "Home", FormMethod.Post))
   {
   <input type="hidden" value="@Model.Username" name="username" />
   <td><input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Получить выписку" /> </td>
   @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Date, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "datetimepicker1", @id = "datetimepicker1", @style = "height: 30px" } });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, вам необходимо, чтобы не перезагружалась страница, в таком случае необходимо делать асинхронный запрос. Попробуйте заменить Html.BeginForm на Ajax.BeginForm или выполняйте его средствами javascript.